# How to hide endpoints on SwaggerUI documentation with Springdoc by User based Authorized Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, swagger-ui, springdoc, spring-boot-security

I want to hide my swagger endpoints based on Authorized user. If admin login they can see every api. if another user login I want to filter apis. How can I do this on java spring boot project ?
[swagger logın](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SsHA.png)

After login apis will show up.

[swagger ui api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWZTP.png)

I can use another libs. I have to use springdoc. I tried couple of thing but didnt work. @Hidden is not enough for me. I want to hide apis based on user.